# .htaccess doesn't work on xampp (windows 7)

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I'm setting my `.htaccess` file right now to use **friendly urls** (manually). But, when i go to the url the server shows me **Error 404**.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

Rewriterule ^register$ register.php
```

I'm really sure that **mod_rewrite** is enabled because i see it when use `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even though `mod-rewrite` is enabled, by default it is not enabled for `.htaccess` files.

**Hold Your Breath**

- Open xampp control panel
- Stop Apache
- Click the `Config` button on the Apache row, and select `httpd.conf`
- In that file, search for something like `xampp/htdocs">`
- A bit lower, you may see a line like this: `# AllowOverride All`. Remove the `#`, which is a comment
- Alternately, search for `AllowOverride All`, make sure it is in the right section, and remove the comment `#`
- Save the file
- Restart Apache, say a prayer, cross  your fingers and hold your breath

Comment: Glad to hear it. It must have been the prayer. :) :) Thanks, see you next time!

Answer (score 1):

This listing may be old but is still relevant so to make it a little more secure it is probably best to add a few lines.

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
Allow from .htaccess
```

Also as a side note .htaccess files slow the speed of the server so it would be best to refer to xampp documentation for best practices.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

if we want to remove index.php form url .First we create a .htaccess file on root directory of project with out any extension. And add this code in this file and so remove the index.php  Application/config/config.php

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Check in httpd.conf you  tag, review this property

```
AllowOverride All
```

AllowOverride authorize use htaccess file.