# Show a 404 page if route not found in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to figure out to show 404 page not found if a route is not found. I followed many tutorials, but it doesn't work.
I have `404.blade.php` in `\laravel\resources\views\errors`

Also in handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        // redirect to form an example of how i handle mine
        return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with(
            'csrf_error',
            "Opps! Seems you couldn't submit form for a longtime. Please try again"
        );
    }

    /*if ($e instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 500);
    }*/

    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
        return response(view('error.404'), 404);

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

If I enter wrong URL in browser, it returns a blank page. I have

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

in app.php.

Can anyone help me  how to show a 404 page if route is not found? Thank you.

Comment: what do you get currently?

Comment: use abort(404);  then create a page in errors folder 404.blade.php

Comment: @mdamia.where i have to use abort(404) ?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-404-errors)

Comment: @aug Post specifies 5.1. That is the documentation for 4.2.

Comment: [My bad.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#throwing-404-errors)

Comment: @mdamia Where i have to define abort(404) ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I recieved 500 errors instead of 404 errors. I solved the problem like this:

In the app/Exceptions/Handler.php file, there is a **render** function.

Replace the function with this function:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {

            // not authorized
            case '403':
                return \Response::view('errors.403',array(),403);
                break;

            // not found
            case '404':
                return \Response::view('errors.404',array(),404);
                break;

            // internal error
            case '500':
                return \Response::view('errors.500',array(),500);
                break;

            default:
                return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

You can then use views that you save in views/errors/404.blade.php, and so on.

Answer (score 9):

[image]> The abort method will immediately raise an exception which will be rendered by the exception handler. Optionally, you may provide the response text:

```
abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
```

is your app_debug set to true? if that is the case, Laravel will throw the error with backtrace for debugging purposes, if you change the value to false, Laravel will show the default 404 page in the errors folder. That being said you can choose to use abort at any time you want.  at the controller level or at the route level, it is totally up to you.

ie

```
Route::get('/page/not/found',function($closure){
  // second parameter is optional. 
  abort(404,'Page not found');
  abort(403); 
});
```

Comment: @mdamia.where i have to use abort(403) ?

Comment: it's really up to you where and when you want to  use abort. see updated answer.

Comment: ,i have enabled true but it display blank page.

Comment: @mdamia.i copied your code and added to route.php but it return blank page.even if i enable debug true it wont throw exception

Comment: do you have a page in your errors folder corresponding to the error number?  in `abort(404)` page name 404.blade.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87850/discussion-between-tester-and-mdamia).

Answer (score 6):

@tester.Your problem has already been solved, try the command below in composer:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Then try once more with an unknown URL. Because I have also faced the same error before.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to check the error type and manually render the 404 view. Laravel already knows to render the view with the HTTP error code that was thrown (404 = resources/views/errors/404.blade.php). Get rid of the extra check and it should work fine.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        // redirect to form an example of how i handle mine
        return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with(
            'csrf_error',
            "Opps! Seems you couldn't submit form for a longtime. Please try again"
        );
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but it didnt work after that i have created fresh laravel project as per the suggested by mdamia.then used your code it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in app/Exceptions/Handler.php (Laravel 5.2):

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \ReflectionException OR $e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) //Si la ruta no existe, mostar view 404.
        return response(view('errors.404'), 404);
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

And it looks like this:[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcVtS.png)

Answer (score 0):

In apache you could be able to put this code in .htaccess file at your main directory and make sure that change AllowOverride Directive  to all in httpd confg file

```
ErrorDocument 404 the\path\to\404.blade.php
```

Comment: .i am using xamp local server in windows 7

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472349/htaccess-doesnt-work-on-xampp-windows-7

Comment: @ Mohammed Elhag. problem solved as suggested by  patricus and mdamia.the problem is with the laravel project .i have created new project and tried it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In config folder app.php change the following code

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

In App->Exception->Handler.php Replace Render Function With Below Code

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) 
    {
    return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }

    
    if ($exception instanceof \ErrorException) {
    return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    } 
    else {
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to the 404 page if the route is not found..

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('404');
});
```