# how to configure xampp server to open php file by default without writing the .php extension

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

how to configure xampp server to open php file by default in a browser without writing the.php extension in window 10

Comment: The magical keyterm for google is htaccess and/or mod_rewrite

Comment: It's done by redirecting all requests through a singular file (such as index.php) then index.php reads the REQUEST_URI to work out what controller and action it needs to execute

Comment: @zanderwar but the .php extension will remain because your router would just redirect to another php script which has a .php extension ;)

Comment: Nah, see my answer below... a bit rough and untested but it should work lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess doesn't work on xampp (windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472349/htaccess-doesnt-work-on-xampp-windows-7)